# Elasticsearch : Replication concept is conflicting with the main idea of Sharding

Tags: elasticsearch, replication, sharding

I am new to Elasticsearch.

With reference to this article for the sharding concept:

https://codingexplained.com/coding/elasticsearch/understanding-sharding-in-elasticsearch

and for replication this article : https://codingexplained.com/coding/elasticsearch/understanding-replication-in-elasticsearch

I have the following confusion.

Lets say we have an index which has 1 TB of data and we have two machines with 512GB disk space each. Since we cannot store the entire index in one single machine, we have to creata a cluster with 2 nodes. Node A and Node B now have primary shards with 512GB each allocated. Now since Node A disk space is full and so is Node B, how will Node A store replica shard B which is of 512GB and similarly how will Node B store replica shard A which is of 512GB when both the machines only have 512GB of disk space.

So does each Node in the cluster have its own primary shard and all the replica shards of other nodes? Meaning each node contains all the data which will consume the hard disk, cpu and other metrics.

I wanted to understand how the replication works, if each node contains primary shard and replicas of other node shards, then each node must have huge disk space which reduces the goal of sharding to split data and store across different nodes.

Answer (score 0):

1. In `Elasticsearch` when you create an `index`, it is automatically divided into number of `shards`, which are distributed across the available `nodes` in the `cluster`. Each shard is self-contained index, which means that it contains a subset of the total data in the index.
2. When you create a `replica shard`, Elasticsearch creates a `copy of the primary shard` on a different node in the cluster. The purpose of the replica shard is to provide high availability and fault tolerance, so that if a node fails, the replica shard can take over as the primary shard
3. In your example, where you have two nodes with 512GB disk space each, and you have created an index with `1TB of data`, you would need to split the index into at least `two primary shards`, each of which would be allocated to  different node in the cluster. Each primary shard would have a replica shard, which would be allocated to the other node. So in this case, `Node A` would have a primary shard of 512GB, and a replica shard of 512GB from `Node B`. Similarly, `Node B` would have a primary shard of 512GB, and a replica shard of 512GB from `Node A`. This means that each node would contain both a primary shard and a replica shard, but they don't have to contain all the data in the index.

Comment: How can these nodes contain replica shards when the disk capacity itself is 512GB and its already consumed by the primary shard?

Comment: Replica shard assigned to that node would not necessarily consume additional 512GB of disk space, because replica shard is copy of primary shard, and that's why only needs to store the differences between the primary and replica shard.

Comment: I also advise to read the following book: 'Elasticsearch The Definitive Guide' by Clinton Gormley & Zachary Tong. It also helps you to extend your further knowledge

Comment: If primary shard already consumes 512GB of disk space, then there is no way replica shard can be stored isn't it?

Comment: Please read above given book and do study a little more, because it seems like we are walking around the circle

Comment: Sure, can you please point me out to which page ? I need the answer straight to the point, thats why i came here and asked. Sorry i don't have that much time to go through this whole book actually.